# Python: Calling a function with a string returns the description of the argument

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am trying to call a function with a string but as I do so the function just make use of the name of the argument for that function.

My function is defined as sortering(attribut) and when i call it with for example: sortering('age') it uses 'attribut' and not 'age'.

Here is the code, I am fairly new to python so it is probably something obvious that I am not familiar with.

```
def sortering(attribut):
 try:
    val1 = input("Vill du sortera stigande eller fallande? s/f")
    if val1 == "s":
        djurlista.sort(key=lambda x: x.attribut)
        print(*djurlista,sep='\n' + ' ' + '\n')
    elif val1 == "f":
        djurlista.sort(key=lambda x: x.attribut, reverse=True)
        print(*djurlista,sep='\n' + ' ' + '\n')
 except ValueError:
    print("Svara med s för stigande eller f för fallande!")


sortering('age')
```

The list "djurlista" is a list of strings and each string is an object 'Djur' with attributes: art, namn, ålder, kön, gravid

Here is that code:

```
class Djur:
def __init__(self, art, namn, ålder, kön, gravid):
    self.art = art
    self.namn = namn
    self.age = ålder
    self.gender = kön
    self.gravid = gravid

    x = Djur(art, namn, ålder, kön, gravid)
    self.djurlista.append(x)
def __str__(self):
    return ("Art: " + str(self.art) + " " + "\n"
            "Namn: " + str(self.namn) + " " + "\n"
            "Ålder: " + str(self.age) + " " + "\n"
            "Kön: " + str(self.gender) + " " + "\n"
            "Gravid: " + str(self.gravid))
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)
```

Comment: What does *djurlista* contain?

Comment: What is the data type for `djurlista`?

Comment: Data type is strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `x.attribut` (where *attribut* is a string, and *x* is a *Djur* instance), you should use [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Functions - **getattr**(*object, name[, default]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```py
djurlista.sort(key=lambda x: getattr(x, attribut))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use x[attribut] and not x.attribut

```
def sortering(attribut):
 try:
    val1 = input("Vill du sortera stigande eller fallande? s/f")
    if val1 == "s":
        djurlista.sort(key=lambda x: x[attribut])
        print(*djurlista,sep='\n' + ' ' + '\n')
    elif val1 == "f":
        djurlista.sort(key=lambda x: x[attribut], reverse=True)
        print(*djurlista,sep='\n' + ' ' + '\n')
 except ValueError:
    print("Svara med s för stigande eller f för fallande!")

sortering('age')
```

Comment: If I do that i get the following error: TypeError: 'Djur' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to get the .attribut parameter from a global class/obj called x (via x.attribut), which should be throwing an error if it doesn't exist, but may not be if it's stored in your python cli somehow.

If you remove the x. before the reference to attribut, do you still get the same error?

Comment: If i do this then the sort() does not do what it is supposed to

Comment: Sorry, completely missed the lambda expression. Would you be able to share the data type / definition of djurlista in the original post?

Comment: It is a list of strings

Comment: Thanks! Should've realized you were dealing with objects attributes from the name... sorry. At this point, it looks like CristiFati already answered this correctly :) Good luck!